# Why can't I turn on my pc with my remote control?

Tags: windows, remote-control

I want to use my remote control to turn on my pc but it doesn't work. I can turn off my pc with the remote control. How can I also use my remote control to turn on my pc? Is this a missing bios killswitch or a os setup?

Comment: When you say remote-control. Are you talking about a physical device or a remote-desktop service.

Comment: @AceLegend: physical device

Comment: Oh, okay. I can't help, Darth  Android seems to be getting on to something though.

Comment: @AceLegend: I think my mainboard doesn't support wake-on usb. Do you know?

Comment: Yep. It doesn't appear to support Wake-on USB according to it's site.

http://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68C-S%20UCC/?cat=Specifications

Comment: @AceLegend: Thank you :). Is there other posibility? A hardware mod or something?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You might want to post another question asking about hardware modifications for enabling Wake-On USB, but I am not aware of any such mod. For now, I guess your going to have to walk over and press the dumb little on button. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a hardware thing. The BIOS/Motherboard generally must support Wake-On-USB (assuming the IR receiver is a USB device), and the receiver must know to send the wake-up signal when it sees the power button being pressed.

Your best bet for finding this and getting it working easily is to find a motherboard which comes with a remote for this purpose. Asus has made motherboard + remote combos that were targeted at media center PCs that explicitly support this.

Comment: My remote-control is usb and my mainboard is asrock n68c-s. Is this wake-on usb supported?